# Numpy Arange generating values of inconsistent decimal points

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-science

Can someone explain me what's happening here?

Why is there more decimal points for 0.3 and 0.7 values. 
I just want 1 decimal point values.

```py
threshold_range = np.arange(0.1,1,0.1)
threshold_range.tolist()
```

```
[Output]: [0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7000000000000001, 0.8, 0.9]
```

Comment: This is correct behavior.  This occurs because python, like most programming languages, cannot EXACTLY represent some decimals due to floating point limitations.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: Thats odd, its printing out fine for me.

Comment: @tnknepp Thanks for that comment. That's the part I was curious about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `np.round`

**Ex.**

```
import numpy as np

threshold_range = np.arange(0.1,1,0.1)
print(threshold_range.tolist())
print(np.round(threshold_range, 2).tolist())
```

**O/P:**

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7000000000000001, 0.8, 0.9]
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But I curious as to why it was acting up. Since you gave a solution to fix it first, I will mark it as the answer. As for the why, @tnknepp answered it in the comments.

Comment: @Saed [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502122/python-numpy-floating-point-text-precision) Python/numpy floating-point text precision behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: You can simply use *round* function:

```
threshold_range = np.arange(0.1,1,0.1).round(1)
threshold_range.tolist() # [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
```

Reason of error: I think it has to do with floating point precision ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to mark the above one as the answer, as it that was the first response (just like yours) :)